# Problem submitting existing app to iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store, xcode-organizer

I have an app that is already in the App Store.

For this current build I made a new project (I rebuilt everything from scratch) and signed it with my previous application key.

When I try to submit it to the App Store through XCode Organizer I get the error:

> **No Suitable Application Records Were Found:**
>       Please make sure that you have set up a record for this application on iTunes Connect

What do I need to change in order for this new project to be recognized as the existing app I have in the App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the exact same identifier as before in your Info.plist file?  You will probably also need to bump up the version number and make sure that iTunes Connect knows you want to create an update.

Comment: was it the version number or the identifier?

Comment: It's almost ALWAYS the version number in this case :)